# Rake command works in terminal but not in crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, shell, cron

I try to execute this crontab line :

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'source $HOME/.bash_profile && cd /home/uservm/RubymineProjects/ && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake accr:generate_pdf'
```

If I execute `cd /home/uservm/RubymineProjects/ && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake accr:generate_pdf` in terminal it works perfectly but not in cron

Answer (score 0):

This is because crontab runs in different environment than the normal user(when you type in terminal). So you need to specify your ruby installation path:

Run:

```
$ which ruby
```

Copy your ruby path and then, change your crontab to

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'source $HOME/.bash_profile && cd /home/uservm/RubymineProjects/ && /path/to/ruby RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake accr:generate_pdf
```

If this didn't solve then run `$ which bundle` and replace ruby path with this bundle path and see if it works.

This should solve your problem. For more: [See this](https://dev.to/imadityang/comment/6j9o)

Comment: I modified as this but it still not working : */1 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'source $HOME/.bash_profile && cd /home/uservm/RubymineProjects && /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby  RAILS_ENV=development /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle exec rake accr:generate_pdf'

Comment: Sorry, There's a slight error, you need RAILS_ENV before ruby.
Try this `source $HOME/.bash_profile && cd /home/uservm/RubymineProjects && RAILS_ENV=development /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby bundle exec rake accr:generate_pdf`

Comment: Or this: `source $HOME/.bash_profile && cd /home/uservm/RubymineProjects && RAILS_ENV=development /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle exec rake accr:generate_pdf`

Comment: WAIT WAIT WAIT! You're trying to run the job every 1 sec? `*/1 * * * *` . If so then you can't. Cronjobs starts working in minutes, so minimum time you should give is 1 minute.

Comment: No i try to execute every minute :)

Comment: Still not working?

Can you give whenever gem a try - https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: I tried to use the gem but I can't use gems on production server. When I push the modification, @ ````bundle install```` step  the script stops....